# Sign Out all Users With Clearance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

We have an update coming for which we need all users to sign out and sign in again.

I've tried changing the key in `session_store.rb` but that doesn't work. We are using [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) for authentication, so was wondering if there is a way to end all current sessions with clearance forcing everyone to sign-in again?

Answer (score 1):

Typing this in your production console will do it:

```
User.all.each { |u| u.reset_remember_token! }
```